# How to get the path for multiple selected images from gallery?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am using 3rd party library BSImagePicker for multiple selection of Images from gallery. I want to get the path of these selected images in an array and I want to show all the selected images in a new UIViewController. I have tried a lot of things but no luck.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Please also show what you have tried what errors you have got.

Comment: @RobLang thanks for the suggestion, will keep all these things in my mind for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with respect to the documentation on github:
https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker

You do get a selection event for an asset

```
let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()

bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
      // User selected an asset.
      // Do something with it, start upload perhaps?
    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
      // User deselected an assets.
      // Do something, cancel upload?
    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
      // User cancelled. And this where the assets currently selected.
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
      // User finished with these assets
}, completion: nil)
```

It is very important to understand, that the photo library now no more returns a URL to an image, as it once did with ALAssetLibrary.
Now you will have a reference to a PHAsset item. This one may contain multiple images (e.g. LivePhoto Video and the related Preview Image).

Thus you could either store all the PHAssets in an array or even access the images already and store the images. (I would recommend to stick to the PHAsset approach, as the images might blow up your internal ram).

If you then want to display the images, use this in a lazy loading approach:

```
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat
options.synchronous = true // Set it to false for async callback

let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
imageManager.requestImageForAsset(<!#assetfromaboce#!>,
                                  targetSize: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(100), CGFloat(100)),
                                  contentMode: .AspectFill,
                                  options: options,
                                  resultHandler: { (resultThumbnail : UIImage?, info : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in

                                                   // Assign your thumbnail which is the *resultThumbnail*
                                                  }
```

Comment: No need to store the PHAsset. You could make do with just a string, the LocalIdentifier of the PHAsset and then fetch assets with that string. More memory efficient.

Comment: Also see: [What is LocalIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phobject/1622400-localidentifier) and [How to Fetch PHAsset with LocalIdentifiers](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phasset/1624732-fetchassets)

Comment: True, as long as there is a way to access the PHAsset from it, as the PHAsset is already being provided, I think it is easier for him ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example on their github repository. 
A snippet I found on their github:

```
bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Selected: \(asset)")
    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Deselected: \(asset)")
    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Cancel: \(assets)")
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Finish: \(assets)")
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This returns only one PHAsset if I am not wrong? The OP could use LocalIdentifier property of the PHAsset but I think to get LocalIdentifiers of all selected images, he will have to keep record of them in select's completion block. Like appending the identifier string into a nsmutablearray

Comment: I have already tried this, this is not giving path for selected images. I want to copy all the images selected and show on a new UIViewController.

Comment: @NSNoob what is OP ? How will I get the URL path of selected images that is my main question ?

Comment: You are the OP. The Theory being, everytime you select an image, the completion block for select will be called and provide you the selected PHAsset and print "selected: Asset etc etc". You can use the [localidentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phobject/1622400-localidentifier) property to keep a track of which images were selected and use them in whatever way you want

Comment: As long as you have the LocalIdentifier, you don't need a URL Path, you can fetch PHAssets with those identifiers [like this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phasset/1624732-fetchassets)